# SDL_image visual glitch on OS X El Capitan

Tags: python, c, sdl, osx-elcapitan, visual-glitch

When trying to load and display bitmaps using Allegro 5 in C or PyGame in Python (both use SDL), instead, it renders a glitch (see screenshot below).

I tried googling it and found that it could be related to SDL_image incompatibilities with OS X El Capitan, but no solutions. Anyone?

Currently, I tried:

- Installing SDL_image 1.2.10 (latest compatible release). ***Nope!***
- Installing SDL_image 1.2.10 with Homebrew via a custom formula. ***Also nothing!***

On the screenshot, those random pixels should be three red brick bitmaps. By the way, I'm using those functions to load and draw the bitmap, respectively:

```
tileset[0] = al_load_bitmap("./data/gfx/bricks.png");
al_draw_bitmap(tileset[0], pos_x, pos_y, 0);
```

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 1):

The bug is actually with SDL_image under El Capitan.  There is a workaround by downgrading SDL_image to 1.2.10 (*not* SDL).  It's possible you may have installed SDL 1.2.10 but still have SDL_image 1.2.12. Try removing and force installing the correct version.

See here for details:

https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/284/max-osx-el-capitan-using-the-deprecated

I've tried this fix myself and Pygame is working fine under 10.11 now.

Comment: Let me correct my question... I've actually downgraded SDL_image, not SDL.

Comment: Have you confirmed you don't have multiple copies of the library installed.  My first suspicion would be that another version of SDL_image is lurking around.

Did you recompile Pygame after fixing the SDL_image version?

Comment: I don't really know the library paths on OS X. I forced recompiling Allegro and it didn't work still.